# No DB-connection after idle time in Grails App (Hibernate, Tomcat, mysql)

Tags: mysql, grails

I have Grails App running on a Tomcat. After deploying the app everything works fine. Then after a few hours of inactivity it won't work anymore.

my datasource.groovy:

```
production {
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myapp?autoReconnect=true"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "user"
        password = "password"
        properties {
            maxActive = 100
            maxIdle = 25
            minIdle = 5
            maxAge  = 10 * 60000
            initialSize = 5
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 10000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 6000
            maxWait = 300
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=true
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationInterval = 15000
        }
    }
}
```

catalina.out:

```
May 20, 2015 2:03:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 44068 ms
2015-05-21 02:17:23,048 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,419,946 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 169 milliseconds ago.
2015-05-21 02:17:23,113 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR support.TransactionTemplate  - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: Hibernate operation: could not prepare statement; SQL [select this_.id as id1_3_0_, this_.version as version2_3_0_, this_.account_expired as account_3_3_0_, this_.account_locked as account_4_3_0_, this_.birthday as birthday5_3_0_, this_.departure as departur6_3_0_, this_.email as email7_3_0_, this_.enabled as enabled8_3_0_, this_.first_name as first_na9_3_0_, this_.joining as joining10_3_0_, this_.last_name as last_na11_3_0_, this_.`password` as passwor12_3_0_, this_.password_expired as passwor13_3_0_, this_.role_id as role_id14_3_0_, this_.username as usernam15_3_0_ from user this_ where (this_.username=?) limit ?]; Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,419,946 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 169 milliseconds ago.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,419,946 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 169 milliseconds ago.
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findWhere(GormStaticApi.groovy:622)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService$_loadUserByUsername_closure1.doCall(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:64)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:815)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:715)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:63)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:81)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:76)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,419,946 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 169 milliseconds ago.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3720)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4160)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5372)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3620)
... 20 more
2015-05-21 02:18:05,539 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Communications link failure
```

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problems too - our app's datasource block now looks like this:

```
    dataSource {
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySql5InnoDbDialect
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp?autoreconnect=true"
        username = "[username]"
        password = "[password]"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
           testOnBorrow = true
           testWhileIdle = true
           testOnReturn = false
           maxActive = 50
           maxIdle = 25
           minIdle = 5
           initialSize = 5
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
           maxWait = 10000
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that MySQL Connector/J's documentation has stated (at this point for something like 10 years), that using `autoreconnect` is not recommended. But people keep recommending it for some reason...